# How to display TreeView items to ListView Items in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have the tree view in my windows application and in the tree view with the checkboxes and I have the Some "parent nodes" and some "child nodes" and i want to CHECK AND UNCHECK the parent and child nodes at a time on clicking the "Check All" and "Uncheck All" button... How should i do this?

Now, If i click particular Parent node as well as subfolders, It should be display it in listview!

enter code here

```
namespace howto_treeview_select_subtree
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            trvMeals.CheckBoxes = true;
            foreach (TreeNode node in trvMeals.Nodes)
            {
                ExpandNode(node);
            }


            trvMeals.SelectedNode = trvMeals.Nodes[0];
            foreach (TreeNode node in trvMeals.Nodes)
            {
                node.Checked = true;
            }
        }
        private void ExpandNode(TreeNode node)
        {
            node.EnsureVisible();
            foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
            {
                ExpandNode(child);
            }
        }


        private void trvMeals_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode node = e.Node;
            bool is_checked = node.Checked;
            foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
            {
                child.Checked = is_checked;
            }
            trvMeals.SelectedNode = node;
        }

        private void trvMeals_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in trvMeals.Nodes)
            {
                node.Checked = true;
                CheckChildren(node, true);
            }
            //foreach (TreeNode node in trvMeals.Nodes)
            //{
            //    node.Checked = true;

            //}
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (TreeNode node in trvMeals.Nodes)
            {
                node.Checked = false;

            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           listView1.Text = (listView1 + "\n") + trvMeals.SelectedNode.Text;
            //foreach (TreeNode node in trvMeals.Nodes)
            //{
            //    RcTxt.Text = RcTxt.Text + trvMeals.SelectedNode.Text;
            //}
        }

        private void CheckChildren(TreeNode rootNode, bool isChecked)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in rootNode.Nodes)
            {
                CheckChildren(node, isChecked);
                node.Checked = isChecked;
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The checking/unchecking child nodes happens by default when you check/uncheck a parent node. When using a Button all you need to do is check/uncheck in code, either the root or the selected node.  What do you want to happen exactly in the ListView? One node, child nodes, how should it look. Unclear at the moment!

Comment: @TaW ... Actually, how to select all the parent node and childNode progrmatically? and after checking the any nodes in a parent node, it should display it into the listView

Comment: using checkboxes and if i select on parent checkboxes it should select parent node as well as childNode and those selected node should be exported into a listview...

Comment: Only __one__ Node can be _selected_ . E.G: ` treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes[1];`.  To check: `treeView1.Nodes[1].Checked = true;` You didn't tell just __what__ the listview should contain. Please be (much) more explicit!!!

Comment: @TaW... Listview doen't contain anything, we just need to export it to ListView! If i am going to select the selected Node that should display on the listview!

Comment: You can add the Text of the Node to a new ListViewItem: `listView1.Items.Add(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text);` or maybe in the `AfterSelect` write `listView1.Items.Add(e.Node.Text);`

Comment: @TaW Thnq so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is that you can create event handler for `AfterSelect` event of the `TreeView`.

Something like this

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
    //grab the listView object and sender as TreeView. 
    //grab whatever you need from the TreeView
    //Put whatever you need in the listView
}
```

To do the checking and unchecking, creates another event handler for `TreeView` event `AfterCheck`.

```
private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
    TreeView view = sender as TreeView;         
    //Access the treeview nodes, check/uncheck them
}
```

Edit:

Expanded code:

```
private void updateChildrenNodes(TreeNode node, bool isChecked) //recursive call
{
    node.Checked = isChecked;
    if (node.Nodes.Count > 0) //has children, do recursive call            
        foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
            updateChildrenNodes(childNode, isChecked);            
}

private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    TreeView view = sender as TreeView;
    TreeNode node = view.SelectedNode;
    bool isChecked = node.Checked;
    updateChildrenNodes(node, isChecked);
}

List<TreeNode> checkedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    TreeView treeView = sender as TreeView;
    listView1.Clear(); //reset all the nodes
    nodes.Clear(); //clears the list

    //grab whatever you need from the TreeView, check if the TreeNode is checked
    //do the same trick by recursive call to put the checked nodes to checkedNodes list

    foreach (TreeNode checkedNode in checkedNodes)
    {
        //do something, use this info to put in listView1
    }            
}
```

I have expanded the code such that you have better idea. Hope it may help.

Note: I haven't thoroughly checked the code since it may take sometime, but I believe this should be sufficient for you to get the necessary tools to use as well as the basic idea.

Comment: @SantoshKokatnur I have expanded the code for further clarification... I believe is sufficient for you to get the idea.

Comment: after_select  listview1.items.add(trvMeals.SelectedNode.Text); its repeating when i again clicked on checkboxes

Comment: But in your code, _AfterSelect seems to be empty, Sir. private void trvMeals_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: private void trvMeals_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {         
              listView1.Items.Add(trvMeals.SelectedNode.Text);            
        }

Comment: I see... is your item added multiple times?

Comment: yeah Exactly... its adding multiple time when i click on checkboxes

Comment: The problem seems to be that the events AfterSelect and AfterCheck may be fired together. Actually we should better continue in the chat room.

Comment: I am not able to chat, because I have less reputation to chat!

Comment: yeah, I will be waiting for your needful explanation!

Comment: So basically, what happened was two events are fired at the same time, and you need to know (1) the sequence of the events. By knowing this, you can know what event actually occurred first and you can consider whether to get this event or to go to the next one. (2) Some way to reject the result of another event. This can be done by a couple of ways, but I have limited space to explain here. It is best of you can search for how to cancel one event fired when two happened at the same time or, alternatively, by creating a variable to store your "state". This way you control to accept/ignore event

Comment: The thing with programming is, the best person to solve the problem is actually the programmer himself since he can access what he does freely and readily while others have overhead to replicate what he/she is doing. That being said, I cannot be sure about the cause of issue you mention, except that there seems to be unwanted recursive call somewhere in your code, because I have no such access to the code (which I believe you have changed). You should trace with your debugger why it is so. Then, it will be easier for you to know what is the case. If you are still stuck, then you may post new Q

Comment: I will try to execute this task, if not possible for me to execute, then I will add new post for regarding this issue...

Comment: Yes, that is a good approach, I believe. Hope you can settle the issues you have.